# Angular http service loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-http

Today i'm facing a new problem with services.

I'm trying to make an http service but when I try to store, in my service, the Observable object returned by http.get.map - my app crashs.

I wanted to achieve a "system" where the service loops to update datas and the components which subscribed to the observable update its data according to the service's data.

Here is the code :

afficheur.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HardwareService} from "../../services/hardware.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'afficheur',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/hardware/afficheur.component.html'
})
export class AfficheurComponent{
    public state: Boolean;
    constructor(private service: HardwareService){
        this.service
            .getHardware()
            .subscribe(data => (console.log(data), this.state = data.afficheur),
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.log('Get etat afficheur complete'))
    }
}
```

hardware.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable, OnInit }              from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response }          from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HardwareService implements OnInit{
    private apiUrl = 'http://10.72.23.11:5000';  // URL to web API

    private ressources: Observable<any>;

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loopupdate()
    }

    loopupdate(): void {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.update();
        }, 5000);
    }

    update(): void {
        this.ressources = this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getHardware(){
        return this.ressources;
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || { };
    }
    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts :

```
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


    import { ROUTING } from './app.routes';
    import {HardwareService} from "./services/hardware.service";
    import {AfficheurComponent} from "./components/hardware/afficheur.component";
    import {HardwareListComponent} from "./views/hardwarelist/hardwarelist.component";


    @NgModule({
        imports: [ BrowserModule, ROUTING, HttpModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            AfficheurComponent,
            HardwareListComponent
        ],
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
        providers: [ HardwareService ]
    })

export class AppModule { }
```

### Thanks again for being here :D

EDIT :

I got an error when i try to launch my app :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

I think it's related to the this.ressources initialization, any idea ?

---

EDIT 2 : 
In my service :

```
initializePolling(){
        return IntervalObservable.create(5000)
            .flatMap(() => {
                return this.getHardware()
        });
    }

getHardware(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

How can i subscribe to this with my component ? I don't know what method i should call in my component to fetch datas without make multiple calls if i have multiple components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ngOnInit()`, like the one in your **Injectable** class, is a [Lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) which only works with **Directives** and **Components**. You should try calling `this.loopUpdate()` from within the **Injectable** class' **constructor**. You can know more about this on [another thread/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110690/ngoninit-not-being-called-when-injectable-class-is-instantiated).

If you want to set an interval in fetching the data, do that in the component class, not in the service. In the service you should just have methods that return **Observables** (in your case) from calling `http.get()...`. In that way you wouldn't have an undefined object returned and a more reusable service.

Also, [here's another SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316583/angular2-http-at-an-interval) for you to have look at.

Comment: I'll update right now my post with an error i get.
I used ngOnInit() cause i wanted the Observable initiated and i think it's the problem here cause "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined", any idea ?

Comment: @JérémyJOKE Updated my answer.

Comment: The problem is that all my compenents use the same service (provider) so if i create 2 afficheur.component, it multiplicates by 2 the number of calls on the api. That's why i wanted the service to loops and the compenents update themselves according to service's data.

Comment: @JérémyJOKE Added another SO link to my answer.

Comment: How my component can subscribe to an Observable (IntervalObservable) ? I don't know how to figure it out.

Post updated in 2 secs

Comment: I'll vote for your answer, it made the initial thread solved. I'll open a new one to get some help on Observable and IntervalObservable. Thank you again.