# Observable http service

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-services

I'm 9 hours a day on Angular trying to make some little projects mainly with services. Today, I'm trying to make a service that loops on data's fetching and the components update themselves according to new data. I've like 6 components using the service and the standard way to do it makes 6 times more requests that only one component does.

I heard about IntervalObservable but I don't know how to implement it on the component side. (And maybe I failed in the service too ...)

Here is some code.

app.module.ts :

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { ROUTING } from './app.routes';
import {HardwareService} from "./services/hardware.service";
import {AfficheurComponent} from "./components/hardware/afficheur.component";
import {HardwareListComponent} from "./views/hardwarelist/hardwarelist.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, ROUTING, HttpModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AfficheurComponent,
        HardwareListComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ HardwareService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

hardware.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response }          from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval'

@Injectable()
export class HardwareService{
    private apiUrl = 'http://10.72.23.11:5000';  // URL to web API

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getHardware(){
        return Observable.interval(5000)
            .flatMap(() => {
                return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
        });
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || { };
    }
    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real-world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

afficheur.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HardwareService} from "../../services/hardware.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'afficheur',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/hardware/afficheur.component.html'
})
export class AfficheurComponent{
    public state: Boolean;
    constructor(private service: HardwareService){
        this.service
            .getHardware()
            .subscribe(data => (console.log(data), this.state = data.afficheur),
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.log('Get etat afficheur complete'))
    }
}
```

I took the information about IntervalObservable [here (SO thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110690/ngoninit-not-being-called-when-injectable-class-is-instantiated)

As always, I hope you'll be able to help me find my way through this problem :).

```
ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.interval is not a function
```

Regards, Jérémy.

(PS: English is not my mother language, don't hesitate to tell me if i told something you don't understand)

Comment: what is the issue? any errors?

Comment: Sorry, i'll edit my post in 20 secs.

Comment: you seem to be importing IntervalObservable  twice

Comment: Thread edited, thank you. Mainly i've the first error, i'm looking for the good import of Observable (i maybe failed it between RxJS and the other one) and i don't know how to properly implement the Interval in both, service and component.

EDIT : I erased both import of IntervalObservable, no changes.

Comment: You forgot to import `import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';`

Comment: Thanks for that but i got a new one :
Observable_1.Observable.interval(...).flatMap is not a function

Comment: flatMap is an alias of mergeMap i had to import it too --'. 
Now, i have an issue with the loop ^^. If i import twice the same component only one will make calls on the service, the other one does anything ...
I'm on this right now but can't figure it out : 
https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: Sorry for triple post : I noticed that all my requests are in pending then my api return 429 (Too many requests) because all requests are sent in the same time.

Comment: Sorry again, i'm trying something else. The main problem i think is the api model.
I got 1 endpoint for 6 informations i need. 1 per component. I want to fetch it once in the service and dispatch the information in the according component.

I thought about creating an Observable<Boolean> which is the HardwareState of printer for example. Then each time i fetch data using setInterval(), i push a new value in the corresponding observable and the components subscribe to their Observable. A pastebin could help you understanding my problem with some "try" code ?

Comment: @JérémyJOKE, Try to reproduce your problem in plunker.

Comment: Wow i'm watching this tool. Powerful but too complicated for me to reproduce it. I never used Mock for my services and using Mock will bypass the problem of multiple calls on api with http.get().

example response of http.get()
{
display: false,
printer: true
}

With that i've to subscribe 2 components display and printer without making 2 calls to the api, only one. 

I tried polling, make a Subject, for each Boolean i need, subscribing to the polling and .next the value i get from the polling but when i try to subscribe my component, subscribe is undefined ...

Complicated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would look something like:

```
// create an observable which fetch the data at intervals of 1 second
this._data$ = Observable
  .timer(0, 1000)
  .switchMap(() => this.getData())
  // if an error is encountered then retry after 3 seconds
  .retryWhen(errors$ => {
    errors$.subscribe(error => this.logError(error));
    return errors$.delay(3000);
  })
  .share();
```

- `timer(0, 1000)` - produce the first value after 0ms and then at intervals of 1 second. Using `interval(1000)` instead is ok but the first value will come with a delay of 1 second.
- `switchMap(() => this.getData())` - switch to the observable provided by the callback which queries the actual resource
- `retryWhen(...)` - if an error is encountered then logs the error and then retries
- `share()` - shares a single subscription among the subscribers. This has the effect of calling `getData()` only once, instead of calling it for as many subscribers we might have.

**Example** - emit current dates, when `getData()` is called 5th time in a row then an error is thrown in order to test also the error situation.

Here is the working **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NopgsY9J3mFeyCw3Q9bA?p=preview)**.

**HardwareService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class HardwareService {

  private _fetchCount = 0;
  private _fetchCount$ = new Subject<number>();
  private _data$: Observable<Date>;

  public get data$(): Observable<Date> {
    return this._data$;
  }

  public get fetchCount$(): Observable<number> {
    return this._fetchCount$;
  }

  constructor() {
    // create an observable which fetch the data at intervals of 1 second
    this._data$ = Observable
      .timer(0, 1000)
      .switchMap(() => this.getData())
      // if an error is encountered then retry after 3 seconds
      .retryWhen(errors$ => {
        errors$.subscribe(error => this.logError(error));
        return errors$.delay(3000);
      })
      .share();
  }

  private logError(error) {
    console.warn(new Date().toISOString() + ' :: ' + error.message);
  }

  private getData(): Observable<Date> {

    this._fetchCount++;
    this._fetchCount$.next(this._fetchCount);

    // from time to time create an error, after 300ms
    if (this._fetchCount % 5 === 0) {
      return Observable.timer(300).switchMap(() => Observable.throw(new Error('Error happens once in a while')));
    }

    // this will return current Date after 300ms
    return Observable.timer(300).switchMap(() => Observable.of(new Date()));
  }
}
```

**AfficheurComponent**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HardwareService} from '../services/hardware.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-afficheur',
  templateUrl: './afficheur.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./afficheur.component.css']
})
export class AfficheurComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public label: string;

  public data$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private hardwareService: HardwareService) {
    this.data$ = hardwareService.data$.map(item => this.label + ' - ' + item.toISOString());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**AfficheurComponent template**

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">{{ data$ | async }}</div>
```

**Usage**

```
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 1"></app-afficheur>
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 2"></app-afficheur>
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 3"></app-afficheur>
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 4"></app-afficheur>
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 5"></app-afficheur>
<app-afficheur label="afficheur 6"></app-afficheur>

<div style="margin-top: 10px">
  Times called: {{ hardwareService.fetchCount$ | async }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I missed the .share() and a lot of notions you show me in your example. I'll learn from this. I've been stuck all day because of that. I bypassed this by having setInterval in both components and service --'. You make my day.

Comment: @JérémyJOKE I'm glad to be of help