# use Angular6 Service constructor to initialize private attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I'm trying to initialize a few objects in a Angular6 Service but I'm getting an error explaining that one of my private attribute is undefined.

At first I tried that :

```js
private mockIncident: Incident[];

constructor() {
    this.mockIncidentRaw.forEach(incident => {
      this.mockIncident.push(new Incident().deserialize(incident))
    });
  }
```

But i got the error telling that mockIncident is not defined.
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

And then tried that :

```js
public mockIncident: Incident[];

  constructor() {
    init();
  }
  
  init = () => {
    for(let i = 0; this.mockIncidentRaw.length; i++) {
      this.mockIncident.push(new Incident().deserialize(this.mockIncidentRaw[i]))
    } 
  }
```

Comment: You never give it a value, just a type, so why is that surprising?

Comment: Moreover, how is initialized `this.mockIncidentRaw`? I guess your problem are not over just with my response.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this.mockIncidentRaw contain the value, but not relevant here

Comment: @Exomus the only problem was that the array wasn't initialized as you mention in the second part of your answer

Comment: You're right, that's not relevant, that's not what you're trying to *push* to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public mockIncident: Incident[];` is declaring an undefined object.

Do this `public mockIncident: Incident[] = []` so there is an array initialization. Here you will have all the property of an array like `push()`

Comment: For info ngOnInit doesn't work on services : "Lifecycle hooks, like OnInit() work with Directives and Components. They do not work with other types, like a service in your case." [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35110798/9243790), but the problem was that I didn't init the array to [], thanks

Comment: My bad, I read wrongly your post on the type of angular component you are declaring. I'm updating my response, to correct my answer that was very misleading. I apologize

Answer (score 2):

`mockIncident` array is not initialized, add = [];

```
private mockIncident: Incident[] = [];
```